# What to do if I can't trust myself with monthly wages?

Tags: united-kingdom, budget

I work in the UK, like most people here I get paid once a month.

I've been doing this for about 2 years now (on a modest income) and my ability to make the money last has not gotten better (if anything it has gotten worse). I feel like if I could just get a bi-weekly wage like people in the US then I'd be able to sort myself out, a weekly wage would be perfect, I would do anything to have that instead. I honestly think it's cruel to give someone a monthly wage when they're as irresponsible as me, it's like giving 10 kilos of cocaine to a coke addict. Not a single month have I been able to make my money last all the way to the end. I'm constantly taking payday loans, borrowing off friends, etc. By the time payday comes, I've already dug myself a hole which makes the payday-prosperity far less significant.

Is there any way I can turn my monthly salary into 2 halves or 4 quarters? Is there a service designed for people of my 'disposition'?

Edit: in response to all the negative comments I need to point out some things:

1) **Yes, I am sure** I'll be better financially by having more granular wages. I have had jobs in the past which paid weekly, on a much lower salary than what I have now, and I **always** made it work without having to borrow anything.

2) I've already asked my employer about getting more frequent pay (would have thought that was obvious)

3) **I know I need to improve my budgeting**, but that's a lesson for another day. Right now I'm only concerned about receiving my money in a way that won't allow me to go nuts every time I get paid, I feel the main problem for me is the excitement that arises from a 180-degree shift in finance (yesterday I was starving, but today I'm a king) when I have that mentality, all my logic and reasoning and education that I receive from you guys goes out the window.

Comment: While you may possibly be able to make some progress on your direct request (getting weekly / bi-weekly payments), I think you are overestimating the impact that will have on your budget. There are immediate things you can do to start budgeting your expenses, and that requirement is not something that will change based on your payment cycle. If you look up the 'budgeting' tag on this site, you will come up with many different resources that could help you get on a better path.

Comment: 2 quick questions:   (1) is there anyone you could trust completely to help you? Like a parent or someone? Or are you without such a person ? (Such a person could hold your monhly salary and pay you weekly from it). (2) do you think you could get - or would want to get - a formal NHS diagnosis related to this issue, some kind of addiction/compulsion diagnosis? (Because then asking for your salary to be paid weekly becomes a "reasonable accommodation for a disability" under equality law, and you would be in a position to ask for that from an employer.)

Comment: Could users who don't understand addiction, executive control and related issues **think** before saying things like "just be more responsible", "think first", or encouraging credit card debt as well as everything else (it sounds like it would be "as well" even if the intention was "instead of"). This is incredibly insulting - the OP has made **very** clear that he has tried this _and for him it doesn't work_. Respect that experience, even if you don't understand how it can be. Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. What you seem to need is to obtain some general financial literacy. But this is not a skill which we can teach you with just writing a few paragraphs.

Comment: @Philipp - nothing in the question says to me that financial literacy is relevant or the issue. The OP sounds quite sufficiently financial literate. They just can't manage mentally, to control money if they have more than a weeks worth or so. That comes over as a lot more like impulse control, executive functioning, or addiction style issues. Not educational issues.

Comment: "I honestly think it's cruel to give someone a monthly wage when they're as irresponsible as me"  This is a very unhealthy attitude to blame your employer for your budgeting problems.  That'd be like a thief saying "It's not my fault that I took that, it wasn't locked down well enough".  That may sound like a cruel analogy but that's what you're doing, stealing from yourself because the money isn't locked down tight enough.  We all have our imperfections and I don't mean to chastise you for this one, I just mean to say blaming others for our deficiencies is counterproductive to improving.

Comment: +1, this is an excellent question and a useful one to have on the site for people faced with the same problem. I cannot fathom some of the unhelpful comments or why they are so heavily upvoted. This is a well scoped question requesting a specific solution for a specific problem. References to general financial budgeting skills are irrelevant and unhelpful.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this at your bank, but here's how I would do it at mine:

- Set up 2 accounts - an account with limited access (do not order checks or an ATM/debit card) and a second checking account
- Have your paycheck deposited to the first account
- Have all periodic bills (rent, utilities, insurance, etc.) auto-withdrawn from the first account.
- Set up periodic (weekly?) transfers to the second account for discretionary spending

If you can't get a similar setup at your bank, you can always just withdraw  *cash* weekly to use for your discretionary spending, but obviously that limits what you can do online.

Now, that helps the *mechanical* part of budgeting - you now have a consistent *weekly* "income" to budget against. But that's only half of the battle.

The next step would be to do an *actual* budget. List your expenses in order of priority (food, housing, utilities, transportation, etc.) and when you run out of money, STOP. No more payday loans, no more borrowing from friends, just stop spending. If you've prioritized properly then the only things left should be luxuries that you can do without (or emergencies, which are covered below).

The next step is to build a small emergency fund to help with the things that are **true** emergencies that cannot be cash-flowed. That way, when you miss something in your budget you don't have to borrow money to cover it.

You're going to get it horribly wrong for the first few months, and it will get less wrong over time, but you should start to get a handle on what you're spending your money on and get to a point where you can *reduce* unnecessary expenses (like loan interest), and start *saving* money instead.

Comment: "Have all periodic bills… auto-withdrawn from your savings account" Not sure if things are different in the UK, but in the US a "savings account" by definition has a limited number of withdrawals allowed per month—on the order of six or seven—and "all periodic bills" plus weekly transfers could easily exceed that threshold.

Comment: This is great advice for another reason too: in case you lose your credit card ( tied to "sporadic" account ) or become victim of fraud, the worst that could happen is that your "sporadic" account gets emptied and not your biggy one.

Comment: Such a great answer, so perhaps add the following point: **Have a friend watch over**. Someone with better discipline, who will enforce your limits and support you when you need it. In general, having your environment support you is great for this case. If your drinking buddies know, they will not try to entice the n-th drink, and even actively push you for your own good, etc."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78640/discussion-on-answer-by-d-stanley-what-to-do-if-i-cant-trust-myself-with-monthl).

Comment: You can get a 'basic bank account' in the UK which won't allow you to go overdrawn or charge you when a payment bounces. They aren't well advertised, but it would probably be good as the second account. https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/banking/basic-bank-accounts

Comment: @Kevin savings accounts in the UK normally have either very small limits on withdrawals (a few per year) or unlimited

Answer (score 80):

Sort of a strange answer here, my apologies:

If we extrapolate your problem to its extreme, you spend all of your money as soon as you are paid, you can't make rent or pay bills, you are evicted, and you lose your job, and you are homeless. That is one of the *many* ways that people become homeless.

It is possible for people who are homeless to change their lives and become homeowners again - I've seen it happen via social welfare programs in the United States. There are two primary ingredients for that process: 1) temporary financial assistance, 2) temporary **case management**.

Case management is basically a kind of therapy for how you earn and spend money, how you interact with the government (e.g., paying taxes and registering a car, etc.), and how you interact with others (effective resume/CV writing, job interviews, etc.).

That is all to explain (and perhaps justify) my suggestion of **therapy**. You are being your own worst enemy (as so many of us are). You're not fighting your own interests in the areas of love or family or substance abuse, but in the area of money management. There are probably some emotional reasons why you are not able to control your spending, and getting to the bottom of those and working on them is the only permanent, long term solution.

In addition, more along the lines of this Stack, some financial management tricks should help (as the other existing answer outlines), but they might only delay the inevitable, if you're not able to start to exert some self-control without therapy.

Comment: This might be the only answer. Anything that the OP can set up, hecan un-set-up to get access to his money again. So to really solve the problem, he has to get to the root of it, and that's somewhere inside his head.

Comment: Okay I agree with you on the later part of that paragraph but I always pay my bills and rent and car insurance etc, that's automatic for me

Comment: +1 from me, the issue here isn't "I lack mechanisms to budget" but "I can't stop my compulsion to spend money I either don't have or will be needed elsewhere". @stannius comment is spot on. One improvement I'd add to this answer is to link to some debt charities.  If OP isn't already in bad debt the pay-day loans will certainly put them there soon, and these charities will have experts that will help get to the root of the issue rather than just treating the symptoms. http://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/, http://www.stepchange.org/, http://www.debtadvicefoundation.org/ to name but a few.

Comment: I have to disagree about spending all your money as soon as you're paid being a major cause of homelessness.  Instead, it's the other way around: you lose a job, can't find another, and no matter how well you budget, the money runs out...

Comment: @jamesqf I don't disagree. I didn't use the word "major". It's only one of many causes. In one way, there are as many causes of homelessness as there are homeless people. That said, transition back to self-sufficiency almost never happens without case management, so there is usually a personal aspect to it, that often has an emotional component, or link to past trauma, etc. For example, battered women who leave their abusers can sometimes end up homeless if they are not case managed effectively in a transitional women's shelter.

Comment: @Jonas I think that just makes this more the correct answer. If you are paying your bills first but then borrowing money to buy other things, the problem isn't in your budget but in the step where you decide to borrow money instead of waiting, or not getting the thing, or whatever. Some people never learned that skill, some people are distracting themselves from stress in other areas of life, etc... But it's probably out of scope for this site. Some individualized help in getting to the root of the problem will probably go a lot further than fixes for the symptoms. Good luck!

Answer (score 47):

### Nobody minds if you pay bills early

For people struggling, it often does not occur to them what happens if you pay the electric company 3 months worth.   They think some clerk steals the extra and next month the bill is due again.  No.

Actually, the electric company carries the extra on your account as a **credit balance**.  Next month's bill comes, but it simply reduces the credit balance, and so the bill shows you owe 0, shows a balance of a negative number, the bill has a red stamp "Do not pay" and they don't include a return envelope.

The upshot is that it totally works to overpay or prepay; the money is still yours and you will still get full value for it.

*This does not work on revolving credit, which is to say, credit cards.*

My gas company charges annoying surcharges for every payment method except check, so I pay them $400 and they leave me alone for a whole year.

### So pay your bills *first thing*.

The instant you get your check, bang off checks for this month's rent, expected utilities, all of life's necessities that you can possibly prepay.  Pay enough extra that it's covered for sure so you don't have to follow up with a £2.16 extra payment.

Groceries? Gift card. Eating out? Gift card. Retirement? Pay it immediately, no wobbling. Saving up emergency fund? Prepay it.

Since these are things you genuinely do need and will definitely buy, you are effectively "paying yourself first", a core principle in financial competence and creating wealth.

With all your genuine needs paid up...

### Don't borrow

All remaining cash is the month's fun money. If you want it to last til the 3rd, drown yourself in blackjack and hookers. Or make it last longer, your call.

Live with your choice.

Regardless, don't go "oh, I need more party money" because that's silly.

Notice that since all your necessities *have* been paid, you are unable to say "I need more for necessities" .  That was the point of paying your necessities up front.

---

> Edit: the main problem for me is the excitement that arises from a 180-degree shift in finance (yesterday I was starving, but today I'm a king) when I have that mentality, all my logic and reasoning and education that I receive from you guys goes out the window.

By the way, that is the crux of your problem, and that is a financial-education problem.  As a result of education I do not have that feeling at all.  I see my finances not as a "right now, devil may care about tomorrow" planning window, but "now and future money is **all my money**, and looking a couple years out, I want to maximize its usefulness to me." So for instance when a shiny new cell phone comes along, I ask a lot of questions about total life-cycle cost of ownership. When a paycheck arrives, I am "meh, whatever" because I see my money as being continuously earned, not a periodic event.

Comment: I once worked for a mobile phone company and spent ten minutes talking a customer into moving her monthly payment due date to a few days after her monthly check so that she could pay the bill before getting hit with late fees. It may be possible for you to move some of your monthly bills to come due right after you get paid to make sure you don't run out of money before paying them.  (In the long run learning to budget will serve you better, but in the short run this trick may help.)

Comment: I used to pay multiple months in advance a lot during the days of mailed paper checks (in USA) and I concur it works fine, but some nits: all my bills were clearly computer printed, they didn't have a red stamp (computer printer didn't do that), they usually did include the unneeded return envelope, and quite often they still had the computed due date: "Balance: negative/credit whatever; Minimum payment: zero; Pay by date: whenever". _One_ of my expenses (car insurance) even gives a small discount for paying in advance instead of waiting for periodic bills.

Comment: "All remaining cash" - ALMOST - do yourself a big favor and, before you count out your fun money, take a small portion (even just 20 or 30 pounds) and slap that away in a retirement account or investment account, especially if you don't already have something going with your employer. If you admit you're just blowing your money now, your future you will be glad you socked away some money for a rainy day!!

Comment: If your bills are variable, and if you plan to relocate or if your bills are not paid to a monopoly, then be careful.  I once overpaid while I was at what was effectively a temporary duty station — dry dock — and never received a refund when I closed the account.

Comment: Dropping money into grocery store gift cards is a clever trick, but be careful about gift cards and other prepaid cards, they may have fees or recharge rules that lead to corners of the money getting wasted.

Comment: @can-ned_food they may have sent the check and it went to your old address, USPS now has some tech to prevent that.   If things work the normal way, the money **escheated** to the state. The state is patiently waiting for you to claim it.   CA even has a web UI allowing you to query if the state is holding any money for you.

Comment: @arp You're thinking Visa/MC gift cards but OP can't be trusted with those. Retail store gift cards, far less likely, and extremely unlikely for stores with a retail presence in California.  CA law expressly prohibits fees on retail gift cards, and *the retailer has no earthly idea what State the card is in*.  That's the effect of the US common market; other common-market effects occur in EU.

Comment: While this answer may apply to many bills, many credit card accounts will still give you roughly the same minimum payment bill next month despite any amount you pay in excess of the minimum.  So, if you pay three months at once, you've chipped away at the principal but you aren't getting ahead on payments, and will still have to make them on time the next two months.

Comment: @Darren good point, I assumed OP would've already flamed out if he had access to credit cards, so I excluded them. Disclaimer added.

Comment: Note, in the UK, overpaying *does* work on credit cards (or at least all the ones I have done it with).

Comment: "Nobody minds if you pay bills early". No! There are regulatory issues with that because businesses can run afoul of laws regulating depository-taking institutions, as well as banking liability issues holding on to unearned cash. They could be seen as an unlicensed, uninsured bank. Financial sector companies pay attention to this the most: credit card companies will close your account if you consistently have a positive balance.

Comment: @user71659 if the business objects in any way, they simply mail you a check for the credit balance. Trust me, I do this. No one sends refund checks unasked  but credit cards, and **we're not talking about revolving credit**.   They're not bank-like, because the money is presumptively for paying that utility or service bill, and 99% of the time that is what happens.  If someone tried to prepay their gas bill by $25,000 of randomly sourced Western Union wire transfers, *then* what you say would apply.  But the gas company would not abide it.

Comment: @Harper You do that a few times, they'll close your account. It's a sign of money laundering, especially through non-financial firms. You cannot use a non-bank institution as a bank, which is essentially what is being advocated. You're using a billing account to hold on to money for the future. That is banking.

Comment: @user71659 if by "that" you mean prepaying an amount of money worth laundering,surely insensible for expected utility bills, and then asking for a refund, repeatedly.  **I'm not talking about that**.  I have been prepaying constantly with many payees for over 15 years.  It works.

Comment: @user71659 if you have references to support your claims, by all means present them.

Answer (score 30):

### Envelopes

Get yourself at least 5 Envelopes and a nice marker. Mark four of the envelopes **Week 1**, **Week 2**, etc. The 5th envelope mark **Bills**. When you get your paycheck, figure out what the bills for the month will be, put that money in the Bills envelope and don't touch that except to pay for bills. Whatever money is left, split it into quarters and put it in the four weekly envelopes.
Now take the money from Week 1 and put it in your wallet. Don't touch the contents of the other weeks until the appropriate Monday. Only take the money out of the Bills to actually pay the bills. Try very very hard not to take "loans" from future weeks; If you are forced to make sure when you start that week that you remind yourself (and act accordingly) that "this week" is going to be slim because you overspent the previous one.

You could apply additional granularity and have an envelope each for Rent, Utilities (Or even separate envelopes for each of those). You might also want to make a **Luxury** Envelope and/or a **Savings** Envelope.

Budgeting is hard, but a desire to gain control of your finances is the first step... And being frugal now can lead to less need to be desperately frugal later (especially if you end up owing interest for loans, or selling items "at a loss" just to make enough cash to eat.)

Comment: And if you have success with the physical envelopes model, you can later shift to virtual envelopes. Many budgeting apps work on the same principle.

Comment: I really like this idea too, I'm gonna try it :)

Comment: As Harper points out in his answer, rather than putting the bills money into an envelope - just send it to who you need to pay that month.

Comment: @MartinBonner Totally... I have a checking account where I put all of my bill money, and ensure I've got enough to cover rent and utilities, and have automatic checks take straight from that account.

Comment: I was going to post this idea if it wasn't already here. Different people and different situation so there isn't always one answer. For some people the very physical aspect of cash and envelopes helps make the spending money "real" as opposed to a card where it's fairly easy to lose track of how much you have left or what you spend. My wife says this is true for her. It may take more than just envelopes to get your budget under control and stop using PayDay loans but don't give up. Try different things until you find something that works.

Comment: This is exactly what I did to make sure my scholarship money lasted the entire semester :) Little envelopes!

Comment: This is harder in the UK as we are a very electronic money society. His wages will be paid into his bank and he might have to travel an hour to withdraw that amount of money. Cash machines limit the amount you can withdraw.

Answer (score 10):

*I am horrendous with money, and while I have managed to avoid payday loans and borrowing from friends - I have repeatedly been in a no-savings and no-money at the end of the month situation.*

---

What worked for me, was to:

**Pay myself a daily allowance**

---

Instead of trying to account for the future - where you're guessing how you might need the money, and whether you can make it last. I recommend setting aside **all** of the money at the start of the month - and then only allowing yourself to spend the proportion of the month you've already passed.

That is, if you have £900 after bills*, you have:

**£30 per day**

No more, and no less.

---

Every day, you take that money out in cash - or some other form that allows you to easily differentiate it from your "not actually mine yet" money. You can spend it on what you like each day, or save it up for something big at the end of the week; but you absolutely never spend more than what you've drawn out.

This works on two levels:

- If you want something big, say a £300 phone - you save for 10 days (or whatever it works out for you), and then buy it on the 10th day. You will not be able to overspend.
- If you spend too much and can't afford food - at worst, you wait one day and spend the entire next day's budget on food. You will not be at risk of going hungry by the end of the month.

Of course, it takes will power. There always will be the tempatation to "just spend tomorrow's money, because I'll be good" - but it's a much smaller temptation than seeing a single large number in the bank account and figuring it can't hurt to spend a little more.

---

* Importantly, as all other answers have noted - you *must* pay bills before anything else. The minute you get your pay, ensure all of your bills and subscriptions are paid straight away - everything that's left, should be money you're safe to spend. *I'd also suggest counting savings as a bill, that needs deposited in a non-withdraw account, and as such does not sit tempting you through the month.*

Comment: This is what I started doing over the past few months, with a minor change. If I don't spend my daily allowance, I split it between the remaining days instead of simply assigning it to myself to keep the next day. If on day one I can have £30 and I spend nothing, I then have £31 per day for the rest of the month. At the end of the month, any remaining gets added to my total for next month, and my daily £ keeps slowly incrementing. It feels like a pay rise for being diligent, which is nice.

Comment: @CallumBradbury That sounds like an interesting way to do it. How does it work for purchases larger than your daily amount?

Comment: I calculate how much it's going to detract from my daily pay for the rest of the month, and decide if it's worth it. As long as I'm strong willed enough to stick to it, it's not too bad. If it was going to take it down below about £30 per day I'd wait, but as I don't make big purchases very often it's not really an issue I deal with much - my problem was always making many small purchases as opposed to a few large ones.

Comment: I like this, but I would up the ante a bit. If I save money from today's allowance, then half of it goes to the next day (or spread across the next few days), half of it goes into savings - and I don't get to spend it. It'll be there waiting for me when I *need* it.

Comment: Please note that on 31-day months you would have just 29 $ each.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with money for most of my life.  Now, at almost 40, I finally have a real handle on things, but that is the result of 15+ years of "not spending" as well as recently getting a hefty boost to my income.

The first thing I would suggest is to get the book "America's Cheapest Family".  I've read it multiple times to figure out ways to help my own financial problems.
[https://www.amazon.com/Americas-Cheapest-Family-Right-Money/dp/0307339459](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307339459)

Even though you work in the UK, there are massive amounts of information, tips, tricks, and ideas in this book that aren't specific to the USA.  Most of them show you ways to curb spending or to spend in ways that actually work *for* you, instead of against you.

This family has helped themselves get out of debt as well as people from all over get their finances straight.  They did it IRL before they put together the book, so they know what they're doing.

The second thing I would suggest is to stop all spending that isn't absolutely necessary.  Drop the coffee shop coffee and switch to instant, walk short distances instead of driving/bus/train/etc., buy groceries instead of eating out, and there are more examples than I'm willing to list.  These are all in the book above, but this'll help get you started as you read the book.

Next, set up that budget D Stanley mentioned.  I used spreadsheets (Microsoft, LibreOffice, Google Sheets to name a few) to keep track of who I owed, how much total I owed each creditor, how much monthly minimums were, when the bill is due, and much more.  Within each spreadsheet, I had tabs for each month, so I could track my yearly expenses and see where (all) my money went.

I don't agree (with D Stanley or the book) that having multiple accounts will make a difference, but it can help for some people.  The book offers the suggestion that simply having "accounts" on paper, but not real accounts in the bank, do the same thing.  I didn't bother with it, since the budget was enough for me.

There are accounting agencies around that might be able to help you manage your money, but they are likely to cost you more than you can afford, since you are apparently already spending more money than you make.

Also, **stop getting the payday loans!**  The fees they are charging you can sometimes equate to a 1200% yearly interest rate, depending on the company.  These companies survive on keeping/making people come back.  I ended up having to use one of these companies, but only once for an emergency.  You will also need to stop borrowing from friends and family, eventually, but soon.  If you can't bring yourself to spend only the money you have, you should shoulder this lack of funds yourself, not spread it to the people you enjoy having in your life.  Eventually, they may kick you out of their life because of it.  They likely can't afford to pay your bills along with their own bills.

The last option I'm going to suggest is to get a better paying job.  That might not happen right away.  Depending on your experience, your education level, your industry, and your attitude (introvert vs extrovert), you might not be able to get a better paying job for a couple years.  If that's the case, you can always talk to your manager about an internal move within your company or simply a raise.

All of this takes time, so be patient.  It also takes time to learn the ways that work for your instance.  Try different ways to save/"not spend" and see what works vs. what isn't sustainable.  Every situation is different.

Good luck!

Comment: Sadly, payday loan rates in the UK can make 1200% look *low*. In 2011 it was the case that "[T]he highest profile payday lender in the UK, charges 4,214%" ( https://www.theguardian.com/money/2011/dec/09/payday-loans-get-cheap-credit ). And then there's the 16,734,509.4% loan: https://www.theguardian.com/money/2013/mar/16/payday-lender

Comment: I think more recently regulation has stopped them being quite so ridiculous. Not that 1200% isn't still ridiculous, but most of them are around that level these days afaik...

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. This is about how to live on a low income and/or how to budget. The OP needs "how to resist impulse buying".

Comment: @AndyT, this answer was posted before the Edit was made to clarify that the question was really about "the king vs the pauper" attitudes the OP has.  Still, making a budget goes a long way to avoid that type of mental swing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're not intentionally self-sabotaging and you're not stupid. After all, you've recognised the problem and are trying to solve it. You probably just have poor impulse-control. The solution to that is to inconvenience the unwanted behaviour so much that it becomes enough work you bypass the "impulse" part and have to actually think about it.

Something to consider is that there's no organisational or legal hiccup to be had in multiple banks.

In your case, I'd use the two bank accounts to partition myself. In computer-terms, it's something like having an Admin account and a day-to-day account.

You know how much you should be getting each month, and with a little estimation you know how much you need to spend. So set up one account as your income account. Your job pays that account, and your bills come out of it.
And once a week, it transfers a sensible sum of money automatically into the second account.

You leave any cards for that first account in a box-file at home, accessible when you need it but out of sight and out of mind during the day.

The second account is your day-to-day account and you keep its card on your person for whatever you need/want to spend money on.

This system guarantees you cannot overspend because you only have access to a safe part of your money at any given time.

Where it gets awkward is dealing with food-money. Food is one of the easiest things to overspend on in my lifestyle, my impulse-control sucks when it comes to ordering takeout and dining out. it's just easier than cooking. The problem is that it's about four or five times as expensive as buying the ingredients and making the food myself each evening.

To fit food into the two-account system, you may want to get a third card, dealing with a third account which serves purely as a food-money repository. This is stocked with enough money for typical shopping habits, nothing extravagant, but enough to see you through each month/week.

If you want takeout or to eat out, spend it from your Fun-Fund, because it certainly qualifies!

Alternately, take your Utilities card when you plan to go shopping and account for food as a utility.

The plan takes a bit of organisation, but the discipline is largely self-enforcing. To do anything to break it, you have to physically get up and go find the box-file with the utilities card. Or at least make a conscious decision to use that card when you know you shouldn't.

---

Another thing you can do is once a month build yourself a spreadsheet containing all your income and outgoings for the past 3 - 6 months. Compare your habits, breakdown the purchases for this particular month by type.

I've found that doing this (I'm not remotely consistent about how often!) invariably gives me a solid sense of where I'm overspending and I tend to cut back for a few weeks before slipping again. do it often enough and it'll keep me on the level :P

Comment: I'd prefer having the two accounts in one bank, because in my experience banks exact fees per client and not per account. An account in two banks would probably cost more than two accounts in one bank. Other problems are delays transferring money between the banks and less understanding from the bank manager of the second account who may see you as a more problematic client.

Comment: In my case, (First Direct bank) I use the e-savings account as a repository for any money I'm saving up for specific things (like trips abroad) and keep most of my liquid assets in the other part (current account I think it's called), otherwise I work exactly as I describe above. E-savings account doesn't have direct access from a card, so anything in it has to be deliberately accessed online or in the bank itself. I also maintain an older second bank account which is honestly just vestigial, but sometimes I use it as a burn-account if I don't trust the people/business i'm dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting your access to the funds is probably your easiest solution if self control is the problem. If your bank will allow you to have two debit accounts this is easy. Here's how I did it (I was paid monthly when I set this up, so I know your pain!): Figure out how much your monthly bills are, add some savings (5% at least), then divide up the rest into weekly auto-transfer jobs to move from your main bank account with direct deposit into another account that can be used for buying food, fun, clothes, etc. Borrow from savings instead of getting payday loans, if it comes to that.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, if you are currently feeding any addictions with your income (chemical, entertainment, etc.), then you need to address those as well.  Left unchecked they will gradually consume more and more of your income until they leave you homeless (I know this sounds like an exaggeration, but addiction is a common cause of homelessness), especially when friends and family stop lending money.  If this is not the case in your situation, that's good--it's one less problem you have to deal with, but I wanted to include it for completeness and for anyone who is in this situation.

Comment: The OP was using the 10Kg of coke as a simile :-)

Comment: @Neuromancer We guessed that.  10Kg of coke is probably enough to be selling *to* street dealers.

Answer (score 0):

By asking this question, you already recognize there is an issue and it will be easier for you to proceed.

You need to learn self control and regulate. 
Be firm and decisive with yourself, don't give in to urges or whims.

Seek advice from professional credit counselors.

Credit counseling is often free of charge or cheap, so get in touch with them immediately.

They will offer tactics and behavior analysis as well as recommendations on how to conduct yourself.

Also, reflect on what you purchase and the reasons for buying.
Are you possibly addicted to shopping or simply spend money frivolously while it lasts?

The best discipline advice won't stick if there is an underlying problem in your psyche or emotional well being.

Those would then need to be addressed to fix your problem once and for all.

If you find you can't do this on your own or with friends and family, seek help from a psychologist.

Find information / books on money management.

DON'T get caught up in self help cults !

Answer (score 0):

I'll approach the question in a slightly different way, some will say I am not answering the question but my idea will solve your problem, to a large degree.

First of all, contact all your creditors and ask if you can pay by direct debit (or standing order) on the day you get paid.  So you will now be in a situation where all of your bills (at least all that can be paid this way) leave your account on payday, so you cannot spend that money.

Now you will have a problem budgeting for things like food, petrol etc as these things cannot be paid for monthly.

What you could do here is have a prepayment card (or two) where you can load money, you could have one for fuel and one for food.  You would need a budget to know how much to put onto each and that could again be done on payday, you would need to make sure you only spend x amount per week/day etc.  For fuel it's not really a problem but for food it might be so you need to be disciplined here, make meal plans and stick to them, that will help you spend less.  What you could do is do a meal plan for a week at a time and order the ingredients required online, so you know exaclty what you are spending.

Any money left in your account after payday, is yours to spend as you see fit, obviously try to spend it gradually over the month if you can!